# What is recommended way to store dictionaries and json file type in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, formatting, storage

I'm pulling json data from an API. My script will store this data and add information about this data to a dictionary.

To store the json data, i'm planning on using:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(data, f)
```

What would be an appropriate way to store the dictionary ? Would it be appropriate to convert the dict to json format with

```
json_str = json.dumps(dict1)
```

and save it in the same way as above ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save JSON data in a Python `list` or a `dict`, depending on the structure of your JSON data.

From http://www.json.org/:

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most
>     languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

The `json` library is what's commonly used to load JSON data and store it in a Python object. Note however that the `load` method will return (recursively) a Python *list* if the JSON data is like `[...]` and a Python *dict*  if the JSON data is like `{...}`.

To read a JSON file containing a `{...}` and save its content to a dictionary data structure use:

```
>>> with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
...   data = json.load(f)
...
>>> type(data)
<type 'dict'>
```

If the file contains a JSON list `[...]` then:

```
>>> type(data)
<type 'list'>
```

Similarly when reading JSON data from a URL:

```
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
>>> data = json.load(response)
```

You can always convert a list to a dictionary for example like this:

```
>>> dataD = dict([i,data[i]] for i in xrange(len(data)))
```

By doing so however you lose the order information provided by the JSON array structure.

Answer (score 2):

Usualy i use dicts for storing data, and convert from/to JSON only for transfer data via web. JSON is not native type for Python, so it would be better to work with native Python types.

Comment: "so it would be better to work with native Python types." : I have to disagree here - a widely implemented, language-agnostic format is always safer than a language specific one.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers But aren't we talking about storing and manipulating data within a code? In that case it seems more sensible to use native types purely for their optimization within the language.

Comment: @wrkyle: the question is only about _storing_ (persisting) python objects.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ah, that makes sense of course! there's no reason to store data in external dictionaries.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Ah, well if we're talking about storing things outside of the program your recommendation seems sensible (unless this data never sees the light of day outside of OP's home directory, then it hardly matters at all ;) ).

Comment: I like to json.dump my_dict into a local file based sqlite database by single main index key.  Let's me handle 20+GB of data with ease.